# Select from self-referencing table and convert to viewmodel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

How can i select all levels of a self-referencing table as a view model. if max level was 2 or 3 then i can do that by calling `Select` multiple times but i have 4-5 level menus and i think there should be a better solution for doing that and select all levels.

this is my viewmodel:

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
    public MenuViewModel()
    {
        Childs = new HashSet<MenuViewModel>();
    }

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MenuViewModel> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my Menu class:

```
public class Menu
{
    public Menu()
    {
        Childs = new HashSet<Menu>();
    }

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; se; }
    public byte[] Icon { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Menu> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var viewModel = _dataContext.Menus
.Select(x => new MenuViewModel 
{ 
    Id = x.Id, 
    Title = x.Title, 
    Child = ???
}
.ToList();
```

Comment: How does your `Menus` looks like?

Comment: @HariPrasad its almost like my viewmodel

Comment: Does `Menus` contain Child collection? Can you providing an example how it is self referencing parent/child ?

Comment: @HariPrasad i update my question.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using EF , you can do like following way:

```
public class BlogComment
{
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Body { set; get; }

    public virtual BlogComment Reply { set; get; }
    public int? ReplyId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BlogComment> Children { get; set; }
}    



using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                var list = ctx.BlogComments
                          //.where ...
                          .ToList() // fills the childs list too
                          .Where(x => x.Reply == null) // for TreeViewHelper                        
                          .ToList();
            }
```

with this way you don't need to use recursive queries but As far as I know,when use view model for fetch data , the dynamic proxy of EF Is destroyed.

**about above example**:
just select one list of comments and with

```
.Where(x=>x.Reply==null).Tolist()
```

EF fill children property of Comments.

[Reference](http://www.dotnettips.info/post/977/%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AB-%D8%AA%DA%A9%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B9-%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%AF%D8%B1-ef-code-first)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Id` property is unique you can do it in two passes:

1. Create viewmodel items without children, but with associated children ids. From that data create the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) that will allow you to get any viewmodel by its id. Values in this dictionary will be the created viewmodels alongside their children ids.
2. For each viewmodel item get the associated view model items using the children ids.

Something like:

```
var tempModels = _dataContext
    .Menus
    .Select(menu => new
    {
        childrenIds = menu.Childs.Select(item => item.Id).ToArray(),
        viewModel =
            new MenuViewModel
            {
                Id = menu.Id,
                Title = menu.Title
            }
    })
    .ToDictionary(
        keySelector: item => item.viewModel.Id);

var viewModels = tempModels
    .Select(kv =>
        {
            var viewModel = kv.Value.viewModel;
            viewModel.Childs = kv
                .Value
                .childrenIds
                .Select(childId => 
                    tempModels[childId].viewModel)
                .ToList();
            return viewModel;
        })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

for depth problem you can use one int property like Depth in your Model then you can fetch data like this :

```
public class BlogComment
{
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Body { set; get; }
    public int Depth{get;set}
    public virtual BlogComment Reply { set; get; }
    public int? ReplyId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BlogComment> Children { get; set; }
}    



using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                var list = ctx.BlogComments
                          .Where(a=>a.Depth<2)
                          .ToList() // fills the childs list too
                          .Where(x => x.Reply == null) // for TreeViewHelper                        
                          .ToList();
            }
```

for using viewModel in this senario , I Test with AutoMapper,but when select data with viewModel , the dyamic proxy that EF generate is Destroyed .

Please Note [this Issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1149)